# running command of gradlew signingreport in Visual Studio Code

Tags: flutter

When I run .\gradlew signingReport in Visual Studio code for my app and it's error below:

```
Configure project :app
WARNING:The option 'android.enableR8' is deprecated.
It was removed in version 7.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
Please remove it from `gradle.properties`.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Build file 'D:\Web chat for my business\Cab taxi\Bobby_test\Apps\Customer\android\app\build.gradle' line: 26

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
Could not open dsl generic class cache for script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' (C:\Users\Chanthalath.v\.gradle\caches\7.6\script
s\6md3ju8n4me7h7bbtpcl3taw9).
BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 65

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 6s
```